# spring boot - application starts despite oracle error

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

On starting my spring boot app (using hibernate jpa) a connection to an oracle db is created

```
spring.datasource.platform=uat
spring.jpa.database=Oracle
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

When a specific `@Entity` is scanned and a schema is created I get an oracle error (`ORA-00904: : invalid identifier`) and the app continues to start, despite setting `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false`

What can I do to kill the app if it encounters an sql error?

**EDIT**

I cannot post the entity but it is of form

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foo")
public class Foo {
      @Id 
      @GenericGenerator(name="idGen", strategy="increment")
      @GeneratedValue(generator="idGen")
      @Column(name="id",nullable=false)
      private Long id;

      @Column(name="userid",nullable=false)
      private String user;

      /*getter and setter lombok annotations omitted for readability*/
 }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you show your Entity class

Comment: some info that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938622/sqlgrammarexception-ora-00904-invalid-identifier

Comment: @rjdkolb I fixed that error by renaming a column `user` to `userid` . I have no idea why it fixed it though :(

Comment: @pvpkiran please see edit